# How to set up pyspark in conda environment?

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda, conda

Here is all the commands I ran (in the same order):

```
conda create --name python_db python
conda activate python_db
conda install python
conda install pyspark
```

And then when I run `pyspark`, I get the following error:

```
Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\python_db\Scripts\..' 
for SPARK_HOME environment variable. Please install Python or specify the correct Python executable in 
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON or PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to detect SPARK_HOME safely.
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Might be something specific to the Windows build: I can't recreate this on **osx-64** platform. What version of Python is installed by Conda (e.g., show output of `python -V` and/or `conda list -n python_db '^python$'`)? Are the symbolic links getting created? That is, in `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\python_db\bin` are there a `python`, `python3`, `python3.9`, ...? Or maybe it's supposed to be under `Scripts\`?

Comment: Also, minor note: one can combine environment creation and package installation into a single operation (`conda create -n python_db python pyspark`). This is to be preferred, since otherwise Conda may end up having to uninstall and reinstall different package versions in order to satisfy later constraints.

Comment: Hi @merv thanks for the response. `conda list -n python_db '^python$'` output is blank (Just Name Version Build Channel, headings).

Comment: I don't see `python`, `python3`, `python3.9` in either of the locations (Scripts or bin). Also the version of python installed is 3.9.5 (checked from `python -V`)

Comment: That Python must be coming from somewhere else on PATH. Perhaps retry installing Python, if you haven't already. `conda install -n python_db python pyspark`